# Firebase provider sign-in is not working inside facebook/messenger/instagram in-app browser webview. Error 403: disallowed_useragent

Tags: firebase, facebook, authentication, webview, firebase-authentication

my team uses firebase auth and we recently run into major problems. We started advertising our website on facebook. Unfortunately, facebook app opens all the links in the in-app webview. Google blocked support for signing in with provider through embedded browser, so none of the users that opens our webapp through facebook/messenger/instagram apps can sign in.  Google/Facebook sign-in returns `403: disallowed_usegagent` and it is impossible to sign up. Is there any workaround? Has anyone experienced a similar issue?

Comment: Other than _telling_ your users, that they should please open the site in a real browser … probably not.

Comment: @CBroe, I've made this now 2024!! Really? is this the only way?, I'm using firebase-auth.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure about Google, but for Facebook I would recommend:

1. do not use SignWithPopup in firebase
2. set `Embedded Browser OAuth Login` to value ON for Facebook login app in Facebook developers console

[image]