# The firebase google login is not working on iOS facebook app

Tags: firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication, google-oauth

I have an firebase app. I'm using firebase auth. This works good. The problem, when the users open the link on facebook app these are getting something like this[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Web Google Auth - workaround for 403: disallowed\_useragent exists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65353812/web-google-auth-workaround-for-403-disallowed-useragent-exists)